# Java object model for SQL/MM: Part 3 Spatial

Tags: java, sql, spatial

Is there a Java object model for the SQL/MM: Part 3 Spatial standard?

I am only aware of [JTS](http://www.vividsolutions.com/jts/JTSHome.htm) and [GeoLatte](https://github.com/GeoLatte/geolatte-geom), but they support the slightly older Simple Features Access for SQL.

Comment: Sounds interesting.... I also wanted to suggest JTS, but your argument is comprehensible. Which SQL/MM Features do you miss? Differences relying to the model (Curves, MultiCurves) oder differences relying to methods (Transform, Validate, etc..)? If the latter one then would it be an alternative to use external libraries which run those methods in the application rather than in the database?

Comment: I am searching for an object model to map Geometry instances from SQL results. The difference between SQL/MM and SFS 1.2.1 is quite small, but there is a difference nevertheless. So for me it's not really about the features, but a match of the class hierarchy.

Comment: I fear that there isn't a generic java implemented object model for the whole SQL/MM spatial specification. The closest I can find for this is a database vendor specific implementation as the [oracle spatial java API for example](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14373/toc.htm). I tag this as favourite, because I am also interested on  a better answer...

Comment: Geolatte-geom will be developed further in the direction of SQL/MM part 3. This is part of the reason why it exists, and why it is used as the object model in Hibernate Spatial.